# Fetch into Excel sheet and insert into SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008

I want to import data from my Excel sheet into my SQL Server 2008 database.

I have an Excel sheet that contains different columns :

```
Service tag | marque | Type | Serial
FGT3456     | DELL   | UC   | Optiplex 760
```

and my table has the same structure, but instead of `varchar` values, I have foreign keys (the IDs)

Example (table material)

```
Service tag | marque| Type | Serial 
FGT3456     |   1   |  18  |  27
```

What I want to do is to fetch into the column `marque` in the Excel sheet, get all the marque values, compare the values to those in my table, get all them IDs and in the end insert the Ids into my table material.

I tried this code but it's showing an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>   Invalid object name 'SQL'.

This is my code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_Import]
   @SheetName varchar(20),
   @FilePath varchar(100),
   @HDR varchar(3),
   @TableName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)
    DECLARE @SQL1 nvarchar(1000)
    DECLARE @SQL2 nvarchar(1000)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT idMarque FROM MarqueMateriel WHERE marque = SELECT (marque) FROM OPENDATASOURCE'
    SET @SQL1 = 'INSERT INTO Material (Service tag) SELECT (service tag) FROM OPENDATASOURCE'
    SET @SQL2 = 'INSERT INTO Material (MARQUE) SELECT * FROM '+@SQL''

    SET @SQL = @SQL + '(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Data Source='
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @FilePath + ';Extended Properties=''''Excel 12.0;HDR=' 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @HDR + ''''''')...[' 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @SheetName + ']'

    SET @SQL1 = @SQL1 + '(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Data Source='
    SET @SQL1 = @SQL1 + @FilePath + ';Extended Properties=''''Excel 12.0;HDR=' 
    SET @SQL1 = @SQL1 + @HDR + ''''''')...[' 
    SET @SQL1 = @SQL1 + @SheetName + ']'
    SET @SQL1 = @SQL2 + '(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Data Source='
    SET @SQL1 = @SQL2 + @FilePath + ';Extended Properties=''''Excel 12.0;HDR=' 
    SET @SQL1 = @SQL2 + @HDR + ''''''')...[' 
    SET @SQL1 = @SQL2 + @SheetName + ']'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL1
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL2
END
```

In the first query `@SQL`, I retrieve all IDs from the table Material where the name(marque) equals to those in the Excel sheet.

In the 2nd query, `@SQL1`, I insert the `serviceTag` values from the Excel sheet into the table

In the last one `@SQL2`, I insert into the table material the IDs retrieved from the first query

Is my logic correct ?? Is this how I should proceed ?? Please I need help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
SET @SQL2 = 'INSERT INTO Material (MARQUE) SELECT * FROM '+@SQL''
```

To this - i.e. wrap the @SQL with brackets:

```
SET @SQL2 = 'INSERT INTO Material (MARQUE) SELECT * FROM (' + @SQL + ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it's quite easy and should've think of it from the first time . I imported all the data from my excel sheet into a temp table, and fetch into my mark table get all IDs and insert them directly into my material table. 
This is how I achieved this

```
USE [AxaStock]
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spx_Import]
    @SheetName varchar(20),
    @FilePath varchar(100),
    @HDR varchar(3),
    @TableName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)
    DECLARE @QUERY nvarchar(1000)
        SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO ESSAIE (serviceTag, periodeGarantie, periodeLeasing, marque, designation, serie, entite, dateDG, nCommande) SELECT serviceTag, periodeGarantie, periodeLeasing, marque, designation, serie, entite, dateDG, nCommande FROM OPENDATASOURCE'
        SET @QUERY = 'insert into Materiel (serviceTag, idMarque, idTypeMateriel, idSerieMateriel) select distinct serviceTag, idMarque, idTypeMateriel, '+
        'idSerieMateriel from ESSAIEIMPORT ess, MarqueMateriel mm, Serie s, TypeMateriel tm where mm.marque=ess.marque and tm.nomType=ess.designation and '+
        's.serieMateriel=ess.serie delete from ESSAIEIMPORT'    
    SET @SQL = @SQL + '(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',''Data Source='
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @FilePath + ';Extended Properties=''''Excel 12.0;HDR=' 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @HDR + ''''''')...[' 
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @SheetName + ']'
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY


END
```